# Максимально быстро получить название узла XML и его значение

Tags: xml, sql-server

В БД есть таблица, где очень много записей, но меня интересует только ~100 000.

А именно, меня интересует XML поле.

Мне нужно получить название узла и его значение и занести во временную таблицу.

Делаю очевидный запрос:

```sql
SELECT 
    a.e.value('(local-name(.))[1]','nvarchar(255)') AS NodeName,
    a.e.value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(255)') AS Value
INTO #TMP
FROM [TABLE]
    CROSS APPLY XDoc.nodes('root/SomeNode/*') a(e)
WHERE EXISTS([Какое-то условие отбора])
```

Так вот, выполняется он очень долго... Можно ли как-то быстрее получить желаемый результат или из XML большей скорости выжать нельзя?

Пример XML:

```xml
<root>
  <SomeNode>
    <f1><f1/>
    <f3><f3/>
    <f4><f4/>
    <f5><f5/>
  </SomeNode>
  <SomeNode>
    <f3><f3/>
    <f4><f4/>
    <f5><f5/>
  </SomeNode>
  <SomeNode>
    <f3><f3/>
    <f5><f5/>
  </SomeNode>
</root>
```

Comment: Можно увидеть пример значения XML поля?

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, Приложил пример. Т.е в Root вложено N SomeNode, а внутри SomeNode может быть N узлов из которых как раз и нужно получить данные.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, пробовал так же в CROSS APPLY фильтрацию делать исключая пустые значения, но не сильно помогло.

Comment: @i-one, нет. Просто фильтрация по какому-то диапазону PK.

Comment: А если CLR функцию написать или через CTE сделать, то будет какой-то профит?

Comment: Если записи фильтруются быстро, и медленный именно парсинг xml, то даже не знаю что тут можно поделать. Я бы такой же запрос написал. С _CLR_ может быть и стоит попробовать, с другой стороны, не думаю, что встроенный xml-парсер совсем уж скверный.

Comment: Разве что, вместо _untyped xml_ попробовать _typed xml_. Типированный xml вроде бы должен выигрывать на чтении (но медленнее при вставке/изменении), хотя не уверен, будет ли ощутимый выигрыш (надо проверять).

Comment: Типизированный- это, вроде, заранее известная схема? Не пойдет, у меня разнообразные XML.

Comment: Индекс, кстати, не придал производительности: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735923/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-xml-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81/736454#736454

Comment: А тормозит разбор XML или условие отбора ? Само условие отбора как то взаимодействует с XML. Время выполнения такого же запроса, но без value в списке выборки, а например с count(1) намного быстрее