# Некоторые вопросы про первичный XML индекс

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server

Подскажите, кто имел опыт работы с построением индекса для XML:

С какой скоростью он строится? Решил его повесить на базе в 7 000 000 записей, так он уже 7 час строится.

Наверное, если отменить построение, то он столько же будет откатываться?

Сколько в итоге будет весить такой индекс? Тяжелее, чем максимально доступно для индексирования поле nvarchar?

Comment: Так MS SQL это все локально должен делать, вне зависимости от того с какой машины я Managment Studio запустил...

Comment: дак и XML внутри не из пяти строк небось?

Comment: @teran, в среднем по 20, я думаю. Просто важно прикинуть, отработает ли все за ночь или уже на откат имеет смысл ставить... А то построение этого индекса блочит таблицу=(

Comment: А прогресс нельзя нигде посмотреть? Какую-нибудь системную таблицу, например?

Comment: ну что, достроил? :)

Comment: @teran, нет. Я откатил. Даже, оделюсь наблюдениями по строительству на небольшом наборе данных.

Answer (score 3):

> С какой скоростью он строится?

Зависит от сложности индексируемых XML-сущностей и их количества. Если у вас SqlServer 2014 или более поздняя версия, то прогресс построения индекса в какой-то степени можно отслеживать (см. [тут](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2016/12/22/create-index-monitoring-progress/) и [тут](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139191/sql-server-how-to-track-progress-of-create-index-command)).

> Наверное, если отменить построение, то он столько же будет
>   откатываться?

Отмена построения происходит, вроде бы, достаточно быстро.

> Сколько в итоге будет весить такой индекс?

Это зависит, опять же, от сложности индексируемых XML-сущностей. Но, как правило, XML-индексы прожорливы. Это можно видеть на примере.

Пусть есть таблица со столбцом *xml* типа

```sql
CREATE TABLE XTable (Id int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_XTable PRIMARY KEY, XData xml);
```

Добавим в неё 100 тыс. довольно простых XML-сущностей

```sql
INSERT INTO XTable (XData)
SELECT TOP (100000)
    '<root>
        <item id="1"/>
        <item id="2"/>
        <item id="3"/>
        <item id="4"/>
        <item id="5"/>
        <item id="6"/>
        <item id="7"/>
        <item id="8"/>
        <item id="9"/>
        <item id="10"/>
    </root>'
FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;
```

Построим на столбце `XData` разнообразные виды XML-индексов

```sql
CREATE PRIMARY XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData ON XTable (XData);

CREATE XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData_Path ON XTable (XData)
    USING XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData FOR PATH;

CREATE XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData_Value ON XTable (XData)
    USING XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData FOR VALUE;

CREATE XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData_Property ON XTable (XData)
    USING XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData FOR PROPERTY;

CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData_item ON XTable (XData)
    FOR (
        item = '/root/item' AS XQUERY 'node()',
        itemid = '/root/item/@id' as SQL int SINGLETON
    );

CREATE XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData_item_id ON XTable (XData)
    USING XML INDEX XI_XTable_XData_item
    FOR (
        itemid
    );
```

и посмотрим сколько дополнительного места они занимают.

Первичный (*primary xml index*) и селективный (*selective xml index*) представляют собой

```sql
select
    xml_index_name = xi.name,
    internal_table_name = it.name,
    it.internal_type_desc
from
    sys.xml_indexes xi
    join sys.internal_tables it on it.parent_id = xi.object_id and it.parent_minor_id = xi.index_id
where
    xi.object_id = object_id('XTable');
```

отдельные внутренние таблицы с кластерным индексом

```
xml_index_name        internal_table_name                internal_type_desc
--------------------- ---------------------------------- -------------------------------
XI_XTable_XData       xml_index_nodes_2002106173_256000  XML_INDEX_NODES
XI_XTable_XData_item  xml_sxi_table_2002106173_256004    SELECTIVE_XML_INDEX_NODE_TABLE
```

Дополнительные XML-индексы это

```sql
select
    xml_index_name = xi.name, index_name = ix.name, ix.type_desc, ix.filter_definition
from
    sys.indexes ix
    join sys.internal_tables it on it.object_id = ix.object_id
    join sys.xml_indexes xi on xi.object_id = it.parent_id and xi.index_id = it.parent_minor_id
where
    xi.object_id = object_id('XTable');
```

фактически дополнительные некластерные индексы на этих внутренних таблицах

```
xml_index_name        index_name                type_desc     filter_definition
--------------------- ------------------------- ------------- --------------------------
XI_XTable_XData       XI_XTable_XData           CLUSTERED     NULL
XI_XTable_XData       XI_XTable_XData_Path      NONCLUSTERED  NULL
XI_XTable_XData       XI_XTable_XData_Value     NONCLUSTERED  NULL
XI_XTable_XData       XI_XTable_XData_Property  NONCLUSTERED  NULL
XI_XTable_XData_item  XI_XTable_XData_item      CLUSTERED     NULL
XI_XTable_XData_item  XI_XTable_XData_item_id   NONCLUSTERED  ([path_2_id] IS NOT NULL)
```

Сколько индексы занимают места можно узнать запросив *sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats*

```sql
select
    index_name = ix.name,
    st.index_type_desc,
    size_KB = sum(st.page_count * 8),
    size_MB = sum(st.page_count / 128.0)
from
    sys.indexes ix
    cross apply sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), ix.object_id, ix.index_id, DEFAULT, 'DETAILED') st
where
    ix.object_id = object_id('XTable')
group by
    ix.name, st.index_type_desc;
```

Получилось

```
index_name                index_type_desc    size_KB      size_MB
------------------------- ------------------ -------- ------------
PK_XTable                 CLUSTERED INDEX      16392    16.007811 <-- объём таблицы
XI_XTable_XData           PRIMARY XML INDEX   114504   111.820312
XI_XTable_XData_Path      XML INDEX            69816    68.179686
XI_XTable_XData_Value     XML INDEX            69832    68.195311
XI_XTable_XData_Property  XML INDEX            69872    68.234374
XI_XTable_XData_item      XML INDEX            46640    45.546874
XI_XTable_XData_item_id   XML INDEX            17912    17.492187
```

в несколько раз больше, чем сами данные.

При построении первичного XML-индекса каждая XML-сущность разбивается на узлы, и для каждого узла во внутренней таблице создаётся запись (для сущностей со значением *NULL* записи не создаются). Чем сложнее XML-сущность, тем этих записей больше. Так, например, каждой нашей XML-сущности во внутренней таблице будет соответствовать *11 + 10 + 1 = 22* записи, т.к. сущность содержит 11 элементов, у 10 из которых есть по одному атрибуту, плюс один скрытый корневой элемент, который создаётся даже для пустых (`@xml = N''`) XML-сущностей. Длина записи, соответствующей узлу, возрастает с увеличением уровня вложенности узла.

Поэтому, перед построением XML-индекса, лучше сделать прикидку объёма данных и времени построения на небольшом репрезентативном подмножестве строк. И, самое главное, проверить будущие запросы с построенными XML-индексами, т.к. от добавления XML-индексов они могут как ускориться, так и замедлиться.

SqlServer, по-видимому, использует XML-индексы безусловно, т.е. если XML-индекс есть, и он подходит для использования в запросе, то он используется. Иногда, однако, доступ через индекс может быть медленнее, чем парсинг сущности на лету.

Answer (score 2):

В общем не дождался построения и отменил его.

Индекс откатился быстро.

Провел эксперимент на 63775(Если верить `datalength`, то там XML на 3 гб) записях и он построился за 13 минут => получатся 4905 записей/мин, что означает, что для построения индекса для 7 000 000 будет затрачено 23 часа.

При этом сервер загружен вообще не был и CPU не уходил в потолок => медленность построения связана с природой XML.

А вес индекса для 63775 записей составил 9802МБ, если верить этому запросу:

```
SELECT i.[name] AS IndexName
    ,SUM(s.[used_page_count]) * 8 AS IndexSizeKB
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS s
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON s.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
    AND s.[index_id] = i.[index_id]
GROUP BY i.[name]
ORDER BY i.[name]
GO
```

Что не очень хорошо для БД, которая итак весит 600 ГБ из-за XML.

Решил протестировать скорость выборки на [запросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735559/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B0-xml-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) ради которого все это затевалось:

```
SELECT 
    a.e.value('(local-name(.))[1]','nvarchar(255)') AS NodeName,
    a.e.value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(255)') AS Value
INTO #TMP
FROM [TABLE]
    CROSS APPLY XDoc.nodes('root/SomeNode/*') a(e)
WHERE EXISTS([Какое-то условие отбора])
```

И производительность стала ниже...

Хотя, прочитав документация, я ожидал, что разжеванный XML будет работать быстрее.. Даже вторичные индексы не спасил.