# Производительность нативного MS SQL VS CLR

Tags: sql-server, clr

Нигде не нашел сравнений нативного SQL и CLR.

Понятное дело, что , скорее всего, в легких задачках нативные конструкции выиграют у CLR.

А если брать в расчет что-нибудь по сложнее, что достигается со скрипом при работе в T-SQL?

Например, какую-нибудь работу с XML, где не всегда можно эффективно что-то сделать стандартными методами.

Comment: И не найдете таких сравнений, ибо нет смысла сравнивать молоток с отверткой. каждый инструмент служит для своих целей. Просто надо стараться закручивать шурупы отверткой, а гвозди забивать молотком, а не наоборот.

Comment: Хотя если у вас XML лежит в БД то тут встает вопрос что вы с ним делаете, если вам например но нему что то надо отфильтровать и в итоге выборки из миллиона записей получается десяток, то нет смысла гнать на клиента миллион записей, лучше отфильтровать в БД (при условии что используются XML-индексы и они покрывают условия отбора)

Comment: _"Нигде не нашел сравнений нативного SQL и CLR."_ Тут ([ссылка](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-performance-testing/)) есть немного, не про xml, впрочем.

Comment: @Mike да мне интересно, можно ли ускорить задачу такого вида https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735559/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B0-xml-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 если написать CLR функцию.